# Last activity two days ago? Where?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just logged onto SuperUser for the first time in several weeks, and I noticed that I have "activity" 2 days ago on a long-un-answered question:

[Multi Monitor setup goes crazy after locking/unlocking Vista machine](https://superuser.com/questions/54108/multi-monitor-setup-goes-crazy-after-locking-unlocking-vista-machine)

Can anyone shed any light on what that activity was? I can't see any comments, edits, revisions, answers, or anything. It also said I had new answers when I hit the homepage, but I don't see it anywhere either. Could it be that an answer was deleted?

If so, is there a better way of presenting this (non-)activity to the user?

Comment: Perhaps you were drunk

Answer (score 4):

I believe the [Community User](https://superuser.com/users/-1) "bumps" older posts that do not have an accepted answers and I believe this changes the latest activity date without displaying any viewable changes.

From the Community User's profile:

> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

Comment: I think you may have hit the nail on the head. This question here (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/34772/timeline) was poked by Community, and it doesn't show in the timeline. I'll head over to the Timeline question and report it there.

Answer (score 3):

It's a mystery.  The timeline shows the last activity was February 5th:

https://superuser.com/posts/54108/timeline

Comment: Heyy I've never seen that timeline thing before. Cool!

Comment: @Farseeker, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view

Answer (score 2):

If an answer or comment was deleted you might see a notification of recent activity but not see what caused it.  That's happened to me, though I wouldn't think you'd still see it two days later.

Comment: Nice to see I'm not going crazy ;)

Comment: @Farseeker: no, you're crazy